# Remove parent div if <p> tag returns empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to remove the parent div of a p tag if the p tag is empty. I have given the p and id and used this line of code.

```
$('#contentempty:empty').parent().remove();
```

I have read through lots of documentation and this looks like it should be right, but when i jsfiddle it http://jsfiddle.net/timwilks13/78uQm/ it doesnt work. Anyone know what I am missing?! Thanks

Comment: Your p tag is not empty, it contains a new line. If you remove the newline, it is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use classes instead of IDs (an ID must be unique)
2. The Paragraph is not empty if there is white space.

http://jsfiddle.net/UNZTV/

```
<div>
  <p class="contentempty">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="contentempty"></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.contentempty:empty').parent().remove();
```

Comment: It was the white space! Thanks alot! (and the id's but thats an embarrassing mistake)

Answer (score 5):

You can't have the same id multiple times on the same page, use classes instead:

```
<div>
  <p class="contentempty">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="contentempty">
  </p>
</div>
```

And JavaScript: (it is faster to use single selector `.contentempty` and then chain with [jQuery.fn.filter](http://api.jquery.com/map/))

```
$('.contentempty').filter(":empty").parent().remove();
```

---

You can make your own check for empty by using [jQuery.fn.map][2] and then check to see if the trimmed version of the innerHTML of the DOM Node is equal to empty string `""`:

```
$(".contentempty").map(function() {
     return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).parent().remove();
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? Because it doesn't work afaik  (see my answer)

Comment: sorry about the multiple id's, school boy error, and I forgot to mention it wasn't working with classes either.

Comment: @TimWilkinson You can check the update think that's gonna work

Answer (score 1):

While @NULL may be right about the id's, it can only work if the `<p>` is actually empty:

http://jsfiddle.net/sBpCB/

```
<div>
  <p id="contentempty">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="contentempty"></p>
</div>
```